# Can I send with websocket value of a variable being updated with a Kafka topic

Tags: javascript, python, apache-kafka, websocket

**Problem:** I have an object attribute `.status` that is updated with a Kafka topic, then I send it through websocket. My problem is that each time I ask from the Client side (javascript), then the Server (websockets + asyncio in Python) will start a Kafka consumer from the beginning.

**Question:** Is it possible to have the Kafka for loop (`for msg in consumer:`) updating my `custom_obj` object and send its `.status` value only when asked for it?

### **What I've tried**

This is what I have so far on the server side:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
from kafka import KafkaConsumer
import Custom_obj

async def test(websocket):
    consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'kafka-topic', 
    bootstrap_servers=['kafka.server.com:1234'],
    auto_offset_reset='earliest', #Must start from the beginning to build the object correctly
    enable_auto_commit=True,
    )
    custom_obj = Custom_obj()
    for msg in consumer:
        msg_dec = msg.value.decode()
        custom_obj.update(msg_dec)
        await websocket.send(custom_obj.status) 

async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(test, "localhost", 1234):
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Client side (javascript in Vue component) code:

```
created() {
  const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:1234');
  ws.onopen = function(e) {
    ws.send('Got here!')
    this.connectionStatus = 'Connected.'
  }
  ws.onerror = function(e) {
    ws.close()
  }
  ws.onclose = function(e) {
    this.connectionStatus = 'Disconnected.'
  }
  ws.onmessage = (e) => {
    console.log(1)
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to track progress in the Kafka topic, you'll need to use a `group_id` parameter in the constructor

You also might want to look at aiokafka for extra async support

Comment: No, I don't need to track progress in Kafka topic. I need to track progress in the `custom_obj` object which is updated with Kafka messages.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my answer. Each time your consumer restarts, it'll start from the beginning of the topic unless you use a group id. When it restarts, you'll therefore reprocess the same data for your custom object. Your consumer will always run, not "only when asked for"